# Make Wind Force Field Only Effect 1 Object's Emitted Particles

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

I want each wind force field to only effect the particles emitted by the closest 1 of the 2 planes. As the file is right now, each wind source effects both plane's emitted particles. I want the top wind source to only effect the top plane's emitted particles, and the bottom wind source to only effect the bottom plane's particles. Btw I'm not asking about how to turn the "Wind" off in "Field Weights" in the Particle tab. I already know about that, and the problem is that it turns off the particles' ability to interact with ALL wind. That's not what I'm asking. I need to know how to make the BOTTOM wind source only effect the BOTTOM plane's particles, and the TOP wind source to only effect the TOP plane's particles.

Here are some pictures of what I'm talking about:
[image]
[image]

Also here's a link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mUtE0LIvGokOJ8Q5uQtx-XvUOxKy3sCd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add lower wind effector, bake lower particle emitter, remove lower wind effector, add top win effector, bake top particle emitter?

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that did it. Thank Emir!